# Having trouble with proving this binomial identity. I have taken it as far as I can go.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have broken down this equation into factorials, but I'm unsure of where to go from here. This may not even be the right approach to solve this binomial transform. Any help would be appreciated.

[Binomial transform identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqNqm.png):

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n\choose k}{n+jk\choose jk}=j^n\\
&\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\frac{(jk+1)(jk+2)\dots(jk+n)}{(n-k)!\,k!}=j^n
\end{align*}

Comment: perhaps induction can do the job

Comment: Looks ripe for a combinatorial proof using inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 5):

In trying to prove

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n\choose k} {n+jk\choose jk} = j^n$$

we start with

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n\choose k} {n+jk\choose n}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n\choose k} (1+z)^{jk}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n ((1+z)^j-1)^n.$$

Now $((1+z)^j - 1)^n = (jz + \cdots)^n$ so the only term that contributes
to the coefficient extractor in $z$ is $j^n z^n.$ (The $n$ factors
contribute at least $z$ so for the power to be less than or equal to $n$
we have to  choose $z$ from each factor. As soon as we choose just one
factor to a power at least two the term produces a power that is larger
than $n$ and does not contribute to the coefficient extractor.) We get

$$[z^n] (1+z)^n j^n z^n = j^n$$

as claimed.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Recall that, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nkp(x+k)$$
is $n!$ times the leading coefficient of $p(x)$ (this may be proven by induction). Now, select
$$p(x)=\frac{(jx+n)(jx+n-1)\cdots (jx+1)}{n!},$$
which is a polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $j^n/n!$. For integer $k$,
$$p(k)=\frac{(jk+n)(jk+n-1)\cdots(jk+1)}{n!}=\binom{jk+n}{n}=\binom{n+jk}{jk}.$$
So,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk\binom{n+jk}{jk}$$
is $n!$ times the leading coefficient of $p(x)$, i.e. $j^n$.